# Utilising .data() with FancyBox 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox-2

I'm using fancy box 2 and trying to use some custom data inside the `.fancybox()` call. Below is my HTML:

```
<a title="TEST" data-album-id="5" class="fancybox" href="galleries/paris/originals/paris_001.jpg">';
```

and this is my call:

```
<script>
    $('.fancybox').fancybox({
        beforeShow: function () {
            alert($(this).data('album-id'));
            if (this.title) {
                // New line
                this.title += '<br />';

                // Add tweet button
                this.title += '<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-count="none" data-url="' + this.href + '">Tweet</a> ';

                // Add FaceBook like button
                this.title += '<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2F'+'www.tommyreynolds.co.uk%2Fgallery.php%3Fgallery%3D'+ 5 +'%23image1'+'&amp;width&amp;layout=button_count&amp;action=like&amp;show_faces=true&amp;share=true&amp;height=21" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>';
            }
        },
        afterShow: function () {
            // Render tweet button
            twttr.widgets.load();
        },
        helpers: {
            title: {
                type: 'inside'
            }, //<-- add a comma to separate the following option
            buttons: {} //<-- add this for buttons
        },
        closeBtn: false, // you will use the buttons now
        arrows: false
    });
</script>
```

But the `alert()` on returns `undefined`. Any ideas?

Comment: please try `$(this.element).data('album-id')` not tested but i think it will work. if it works i can make an answer for you. good luck

Comment: So simple huh! Please make an answer, works perfectly. Could you explain why `element` need to be used? Might help future users :)

Comment: You can also use `this.element.data('album-id')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of

```
alert($(this).data('album-id'));
```

use

```
alert($(this.element).data('album-id'));
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/marathonman/xW5gs/1717/)

[fancybox set content types like image, ajax, etc to element](https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/blob/master/source/jquery.fancybox.js#L246)

[fancybox Tips & tricks section have good samples and all fiddled](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#useful)